# apache mod-rewrite to nginx rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, rewrite

I just changed to NGINX from Apache and I am using Zencart with Ultimate SEO for friendly urls I have tried to convert my .htaccess rules for NGINX but I get "No Input file specified" or a 404 error.
My original .htaccess is as follows:

```
     ErrorDocument 404 /404.html


     Options +FollowSymLinks
     RewriteEngine On




     # From Ultimate SEO URLs
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=index&manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=product_reviews_info&products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
     RewriteRule ^(.*)-ezp-([0-9]+).html$ index\.php?main_page=page&id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]



     # All other pages
     # Don't rewrite real files or directories
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [NC] 
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteRule ^(.*).html$ index\.php?main_page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

And this us what I have added in to the virtual.conf in NGINX

```
     rewrite ^/(.*)-p-(.*).html$ /index\.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-c-(.*).html$ /index\.php?main_page=index&cPath=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ /index\.php?main_page=index&manufacturers_id=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ /index\.php?main_page=popup_image&pID=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ /index\.php?main_page=product_reviews&products_id=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ /index\.php?main_page=product_reviews_info&products_id=$2&$args last;
     rewrite ^/(.*)-ezp-([0-9]+).html$ /index\.php?main_page=page&id=$2&$args last;
     if (!-f $request_filename){
     set $rule_7 1$rule_7;
    }
    if (!-d $request_filename){
    set $rule_7 2$rule_7;
    }
    if ($rule_7 = "21"){
    rewrite ^/(.*).html$ /index\.php?main_page=$1&$args last;
    }

        }
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Peter